# Parameter count mismatch in unit test uwp project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, uwp, mstest

I've a UWP project for which I'm doing unit testing. Here's the code

```
[UITestMethod]
[DataRow("123", IMAdSize.Banner300x50)]
public void TestValidCreationOfIMBannerObject(string placementId, IMAdSize size) {
    IMBanner banner = new IMBanner(placementId, size);
    List<IMErrorCode> receivedEvents = new List<IMErrorCode>();

    banner.OnAdFailed += delegate (object sender, IMErrorCode e) {
        receivedEvents.Add(e);
    };

     Assert.AreEqual(receivedEvents.Count, 0);
}
```

However, when I run the above test case, I get exception as below:

`System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch`

I am sending both the parameters that are required by the test case, cannot figure out what could possibly be wrong with above code.

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: Btw. It's minor but `Assert.AreEqual(receivedEvents.Count, 0);` should be `Assert.AreEqual(0, receivedEvents.Count);`

Comment: I'd check Nuget version numbers.

Comment: what kind of nuget check, @tymtam

Comment: Check what versions of adapter libraries are included.

Comment: Microsoft.NET.Test.SDK - 16.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I am encountering the same issue: It seems that `DataRow` and `UITestMethod` together cause this error, as switching to `TestMethod` gets rid of the error.